Spotlesse and java-code-format don't apply No Wildcard Import
The java code format suggest that star/wildcard imports are not tolerated.
Without the help of the IDE, neither the java-code-format nor spotless can enforce this.
Is there any success case out there?
Plainly, using Maven can we enforce the NoStarImport/NoWildCardImport?
Tried to define my own pmd.xml but after adding a single rule for the ruleset, did not work.

Maven can run a command during the build cycle which can halt the build if failing. Will that do?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not really, because I do not wish to halt.
I'm seeking help, being the java code so adopted, I find strange that no one faced this earlier, since it seems that spotless have a good (in size) community as well.

If not “halt build” what does “enforce” mean?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want the build to apply the changes. Like it does with other rules. The rule is no wildcards, in pratical terms I expect the tooling to look at the code, and as it do with format, can look at the imports and remove wildcards to single imports.
